# Why can't I get this span to wrap properly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following HTML ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3L3pq5L5/)) the text "Why won't this text wrap" only wraps once the width is so small that it has already started clipping parts of the text.  Then it wraps.

Note the behaviour I want is for the block that contains the text to wrap as a single item, not for the text to start wrapping word by word.  Note it actually does work - but it only works once the width is small enough that it would have wrapped without the leading image.  If I remove the leading image, it works as expected.

Is there a way I can obtain that desired wrapping behaviour with the leading image in place?

```css
#main-toolbar {  
    height: 140px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;

}

#main-toolbar-text{
    height: initial;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #2196f3;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.test{
    border: solid red 1px;
}
.profile-toolbar-user-wordmark{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: initial;

}

.profile-toolbar-wordmark{
    width: 90px;
}

.profile-toolbar-logoicon{
    width: 90px;
}

.profile-toolbar-icon{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-toolbar" class="test" >
    
    <span class="profile-toolbar-icon test"><img class="profile-toolbar-logoicon" src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png"></span>
    <span class="profile-toolbar-user-wordmark test">
        <span class="profile-toolbar-icon">
            <img class="profile-toolbar-wordmark" src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
        </span> 
        <span id="main-toolbar-text">
            Why won't this text wrap?
        </span>
    </span>       
</div>
```

Comment: Good question. I don't know the cause, or the solution, but here is a workaround: give a right padding to the text block (main-toolbar-text), so that its container  thinks it's wider than it really is, and it wraps sooner. 94px should be enough; the width of the first icon plus the width of the space in between. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3L3pq5L5/5/

Comment: If you remove `white-space: nowrap;` it will wrap as expected.

Comment: @Pangloss That will make the 'profile-toolbar-user-wordmark' classed element wrap below the 'profile-toolbar-icon' element.  I don't what that to wrap.  I want the text to wrap below the image within the 'profile-toolbar-user-wordmark' element without that element itself wrapping.

Comment: I suggest to use flexbox or css table instead - https://jsfiddle.net/k5w9nepq/

Comment: I appreciate all the answers and many do work in this case.  I was hoping for something that didn't require flexbox and would work in the general case without javascript.  As it seems these options don't exist, I've ended up just using media queries to change the display properties when the screen is a certain width, and I get the effect I am looking for.
...as this is also not a general case solution I haven't posted it as an answer, and I'm not sure I can really accept the proposed answers, although I appreciate them and they help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution here is to use `display: flex`. Here's a [guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You should understand how flex works before using it, as it comes with many built in behaviors that differ from block and inline display.

If you don't want to use flex and/or you are just wanting to know *why* this issue is happening anyway, keep reading:

Since you didn't set any width (or min/max width) on the block containing the text and it's using `display: inline-block`, the width of the block is implicitly 100%. And since the leading image is 90px wide, that offsets the block containing the text by 90px to the right.

Essentially, the width taken up by the leading image + the block containing the text is actually equal to 100% + 90px, so the browser thinks there is an extra 90px of space before it should wrap the block containing the text, when in reality that extra 90px is getting clipped because it exceeds the 100% width of the outer div. This is why the wrapping only works once the width is small enough that it would have wrapped without the leading image.

So to fix this (without flex), you could set `max-width` to subtract the extra width of the leading image, which in this case is 90px:

```
.profile-toolbar-user-wordmark {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: initial;
    max-width: calc(100% - 90px); /* 90px in this case, in general it should be whatever the width of the leading image is */
}
```

One subtle caveat: depending on if there are borders/margins/padding around the leading image, you may need to adjust the subtracted width to account for that. I.e. if the leading image had a margin-right of 8px, you would need to set `max-width` to `calc(100% - 98px)`. And if the leading image had a margin-right of 8px and margin-left of 8px, `max-width` would need to be `calc(100% - 106px)`. Left/right borders, margins and padding all affect this.

Due to the above, you may notice that with the `max-width` set to `calc(100% - 90px)` in your case, there is still a tiny bit of clipping (a few pixels' worth) that happens when you resize before the text starts to wrap. This is because of the red border you've applied, which adds 2px (1px on the left, 1px on the right), and the space between the leading image and the block containing the text (caused by the line break in your code between the two spans). Unfortunately, there is no good way to know what the width of the space character is because it varies by browser and based on font size. So to fix your wrapping to pixel perfection, you need to set `max-width` to `calc(100% - 92px)` and remove the space (there are a number of ways to [remove spaces between inline block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)). If you still want some whitespace area between the elements, then you can set a margin (just remember to account for that margin in the `max-width` calc).

Finally: if not using flex or the hardcoded CSS above, you could do this with JQuery to dynamically set the CSS if you really need to (i.e. if you can't hardcode the width of the leading image element, or if you really don't want to get rid of that space):

```
<span id="your-id" class="profile-toolbar-user-wordmark test">...</span>

let $yourElement = $("#your-id");
let offsetLeft = $yourElement.offset().left - $yourElement.parent().offset().left;
$yourElement.css("max-width", `calc(100% - ${offsetLeft}px)`);
```

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of how the proposed solution here works (just for me, there's nothing wrong with it in general), this answer did tell me WHY this happens - which was very useful for me.

Comment: Thanks @WillyC I'm glad you found the explanation to be helpful. I agree that the proposed solution is not awesome (it feels hacky) but I felt that it helped explain why your issue was happening, which was my goal. As an actual solution I would probably choose flexbox as the cleanest option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried around and around, and found no solution with your HTML.

But if you can change the HTML structure, you can achieve the desired result using flexbox(es):

```css
#main-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  min-height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}

.test {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.profile-toolbar-wordmark,
.profile-toolbar-logoicon {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 initial;
}

.wrap_right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#main-toolbar-text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-toolbar" class="test">

  <img class="profile-toolbar-logoicon" src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
  <div class="wrap_right">
    <img class="profile-toolbar-wordmark" src="https://pixy.org/images/placeholder.png">
    <span id="main-toolbar-text">
    Why won't this text wrap?
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whatever - to have it a bit simpler (i.e. few elements) IMO is nicer to work with